# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting new monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor, display-manager

I recently bought two new monitors and i think ubuntu doesn't detect them. I had a dual monitor setup before this and it worked without problems.

Neither my windows 10 partition or grub boot loader has trouble with the new displays but when i boot into ubuntu it just says "no input" on both monitors.

The previous monitors were connected via hdmi and dvi to the gpu, whereas the new monitors both are connected via displayport also to the gpu. Whats weird is that if I have a different monitor connected on startup (via hdmi) and the connect the two new ones they work perfectly fine.

Comment: Were previous monitors connected using DisplayPort?

Comment: No, one of them was connected via hdmi to the gpu and the other one was connected via dvi to the motherboard